# Get user from request with Graphql in Nest.js

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

I want to make a normal Graphql request handler. If the user is authorized - send one set of data, if not - others.
When I make a request I see the following in the console:

```sh
user User {
  id: '11850582-b10c-4c3e-aa94-6de6db2c8588',
  created_at: 2021-12-21T20:05:18.585Z,
  updated_at: 2021-12-21T20:38:30.207Z,
  username: 'test_admin',
  role: 'ADMIN',
  email: 'test_admin@example.com',
  password: '$2b$10$s/1jSCK3AdM1t01I/PDLA.8NxtVmKmnO5CJZZzi68M4wycPH4K86S',
  currentHashedRefreshToken: '$2b$10$/KkuH80Oql1gArlsJf352eyVYhpMEkcDkGza/xS2YlxzFXtab7oEq'
}
user undefined
userCtx undefined
```

And I don't understand next:
Why I see in the console output 2 times? I guess it's because the interceptor works both ways - when the request comes and when it goes. But then I do not understand why in my resolver user is undefined, if it is at the entrance.

```js
// article.resolver.ts

@Query((_) => ArticleWithBookmarkedModel)
@UseInterceptors(GraphqlUserInterceptor)
async articleBySlugs(
    @GraphqlAuthUser() user: User
): Promise<ArticleWithBookmarkedModel> {
    console.log('userCtx', user);

    if (!user) {
        return ...
    }

    return ...
}
```

```js
// graphql-user-interceptor.service.ts

export class GraphqlUserInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
        const request = ctx.getContext().req;

        console.log('user', request.user);

        return next.handle();
    }
}
```

```js
// graphql-auth.user.ts

export const GraphqlAuthUser = createParamDecorator(
    (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
        const request = ctx.getContext().req;

        return request.user;
    },
);
```

Comment: "When I make a request I see the following in the console".
Could you edit your question and paste the piece of code responsible for showing the user object with id, username, etc.?

Comment: @ÉmersonFelinto my code has 2 console ouputs: in GraphqlUserInterceptor and in top of resolver method. Both of them I provided

Comment: Instead of using interceptors for authorization, have you considered using guards? This doesn't directly answer your question and honestly, this is something very specific to NestJS/Express that you can only find out by looking at the source code. Apparently, the "req.user" object is unset when the response is returned to the user. What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ÉmersonFelinto I have one. And if I apply this guard - the request will be automatically rejected with an error of 401. Therefore it does not solve my problem.